# Posting improved version of one's own question

Tags: discussion

I've posted a question that involved several aspects, required the full code and got quite lengthy in explanations and details. Doubtless because of the length and complexity, it went unanswered.

Now I've continued working on the issue and everything boils down to one simple question that can be asked in three or four lines. (Whether or not the answer is simple remains to be seen, of course.)

Is it acceptable to post that pared-down, clearer, more focussed question as a new question? It didn't seem right to trim down the original question, as it would make all the comments seem irrelevant.

Comment: Comments are second class citizens anyways. If you would invalidate answers, that would be bad, of course, but I don't think comments really warrant that kind of protection.

Comment: There's one answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37457314/setting-combobox-values-on-initialisation-and-change-of-other-comboboxes) that quite specifically addresses large chunks of the original question.

Comment: Then you should probably indeed ask a new question if the changes are significant enough to invalidate that answer otherwise

Comment: You can always link to the original.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - I'll do that. :-)